# How to count same value on recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting, android-recyclerview

Is there any method for counting the occurrence of each item on recyclerview ?

Lets say I have recyclerview items:

```
String[] array = {"item1","item1","item2","item2", "item3", "item4"};
```

expected output :-

```
item1  2
item2  2
item3  1
item4  1
```

I already create recycleview adapter, but i don't know how to count the same item.
please help

Comment: you can use a linkedhashmap and store the key as item and it occurence as value. it has nothing to do with recyclerview.

Comment: @Raghunandan can you give me some example?

Comment: you can take a look at the below example. only change is that hashmap there is no ordering. if you want ordered set of items use linkedhashmap

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function you are looking for

```
public void countEntries(String[] items) {
    HashMap itemToCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String item : items) {
        if (itemToCountMap.containsKey(item)) {
            Integer current = (Integer) itemToCountMap.get(item);
            itemToCountMap.put(item, current + 1);
        } else {
            itemToCountMap.put(item, 1);
        }
    }

    // Key - is the string
    // Value - is the number of repetitions
    itemToCountMap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("key: "+key+" value:"+value));
}
```

Now you only need to get items from the `recyclerView.adapter` (if your items are public)

```
String[] items = recyclerView.getAdapter().getItems()
countEntries(items)
```